# Ubuntu-gnome now alone on harddrive, how to remove multiboot menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I want to remove all trace of multi-boot now and make Ubuntu boot up without grub that was installed when Windows 7 was there. Now Windows 7 is gone but not the boot menu.

*How do I remove this?*

Comment: Have you tried grub-customizer by Daniel Richter? https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer?field.series_filter=

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and run the following command -

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will re-generate the grub config files so that only valid entries exist.

**Note -** You need a bootloader like grub or syslinux if you wish to boot into Ubuntu. Therefore, you must not remove grub itself, as suggested in the question.